# Visual Studio 2013 package issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package

I have a Visual Studio package, that adds a window with some functionality in visual studio 2013. If I execute its vsix file, it installs nicely and I can see it in the menu (view/other windows) and the windows open fine. If I hit F5, it also works.

However, if I just copy the package files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions (what a regular setup would do), and start Visual Studio, the package doesn't seem to be detected by Visual Studio and it doesn't appear. Normally copying these files should be sufficient? Or am I missing something here?

The VSIX looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
     <Identifier Id="3db0e2d9-11c5-4db8-9861-6935c8deb654">
     <Name>Test</Name>
     <Author>Test</Author>
     <Version>2.0</Version>
     <Description xml:space="preserve">Test</Description>
     <Locale>1033</Locale>
     <Icon>smiley-lol.ico</Icon>
     <InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
       <SupportedProducts>
         <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
           <Edition>Pro</Edition>
           <Edition>Premium</Edition>
           <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
       </VisualStudio>
     </SupportedProducts>
   <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.0" MaxVersion="4.0" />
   </Identifier>
   <References>
     <Reference Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF" MinVersion="10.0">
        <Name>Visual Studio MPF</Name>
     </Reference>
   </References>
   <Content>
     <VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|</VsPackage>
   </Content>
 </Vsix>
```

EDIT: this used to work in VS2010, but not in VS2013.

Thanks,
L

Comment: Are the rights set correctly? Maybe you copy them in as Admin and VS runs not in admin mode?

Comment: Yes, I run VS as admin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Visual Studio 2012, VS caches installed packages and to "register" a new copied package you need to run "devenv.exe /setup".

Comment: Thank you for this information, I will check this out and come back to you :)